# How to verify properties of two consecutives item in a group made with GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0, fluentvalidation

I am making a fluent validation, where i group by `DayCode` the items inside a `List<Schedule>`.

A Schedule object can look like this :

```
Schedule = [
{
  Daycode = "1",
  StartingDate = "2023-07-12T00:00:00.000Z"
  EndingDate = "2023-07-12T08:00:00.000Z"
},
{
  Daycode = "1",
  StartingDate = "2023-07-12T08:00:01.000Z"
  EndingDate = "2023-07-12T23:59:59.000Z"
}
]
```

After i did that, i need to return a bool by verifying that for all corresponding groups, the StartingDate of the next object should be equal to the EndingDate + 1 second of the object coming before him in the group.

**Edge cases:**

- We could only have 1 item in the group, so we should be able to return true since theres no need to verify
- If we have an odd number we need to only verify the ones that are following each others and stop at the last one since we can't compare him with the next value.

**Ideally i would like to just use linq and return a boolean, but i'm not sure how do achieve that. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.**

```
**this is what i tried:**


RuleFor(c => c.Tele.MustAsync(async (tele, cancellation) =>
{
  var scheduleSorted = tele.Schedule.OrderBy(r => r.StartingDate);
  var scheduleGrouped = scheduleSorted.GroupBy(r => r.DayCode);
  var approved = false;
  
  foreach(var group in scheduleGrouped)
  {
    var groupList = group.ToList();
    if(groupList .Count() == 1)
      approved = true;
    else
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < groupList.Count; i++)
      {
        var currentElement = groupList[i];
        if (i < groupList.Count -1)
          {
            var nextElement = groupList[i+1];
            if (currentElement.EndingDate.AddSeconds(1) == nextElement.StartingDate) {
                    approved = true;
                  }
          }
      }
    }
  return approved;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to sort, if possible, that they are mixed up.

Comment: Try without linq and see if you can get the logic worked out.  Sort by date ascending and do a for loop comparing the current and next item.

Comment: @hijinxbassist i think i got the logic sorted out without linq (i edited my original post) now i need to find how to use linq hahaha

Comment: How about something like:
`RuleFor(c => c.Tele.MustAsync(async (tele, cancellation) =>
{
    var scheduleSorted = tele.Schedule.OrderBy(r => r.StartingDate);
    var scheduleGrouped = scheduleSorted.GroupBy(r => r.DayCode);

    return scheduleGrouped.All(group =>
    {
        var groupList = group.ToList();
        return groupList.Count == 1 ||
            groupList.Zip(groupList.Skip(1), (current, next) => new { Current = current, Next = next })
            .All(pair => pair.Current.EndingDate.AddSeconds(1) == pair.Next.StartingDate);
    });
}));`

Comment: @fuzzy_logic this is code that chat gpt gave me also, and didn't work haha :/

Comment: lol that's why I put in comment, confidence was low :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to attempt a pure linq solution. In fact it makes the code much harder to construct, read, and understand.  Instead break the problem down and use a mix of linq and a for loop.  The steps can be broken down in the following way.

1. Create a collection of groups based on the DayCode property
2. Sort the contents of each group on the StartingDate (ascending)
3. For each group, loop through its items.  Compare currentItem EndingDate to nextItem StartingDate, returning a value indicating the validity of the group
4. Check that each validation check succeeded

- 

```
var validations = tele.Schedule
    .GroupBy(item => item.DayCode)
    .Select(group =>
    {
        var orderedItems = group.OrderBy(item => item.StartingDate).ToArray();
        if (orderedItems.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < orderedItems.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (orderedItems[i].EndingDate.AddSeconds(1) != orderedItems[i + 1].StartingDate)
                {
                    return new { Items = orderedItems, IsValid = false };
                }
            }
        }

        return new { Items = orderedItems, IsValid = true };
    });

var allValid = validations.All(validation => validation.IsValid);
```

The above can be reduced to the final validation bool, I included the ordered items with the validation bool for debugging purposes and to show how logging invalid groups could be handled.